Python typing for nested iterator on list of objects with iterable property
I have a somewhat tricky python typing question. I have a function (generator) that iterates over a list of objects, and then over a particular attribute of each of these objects like this:
T = TypeVar('T')
S = TypeVar('S')

def iter_attribute(outer: Iterable[T], attribute: str) -> Iterable[S]:
    for item in outer:
        yield from getattr(item, attribute)

How would I properly convey the fact that T should have an iterable attribute called attribute that yields S objects? By the way, mypy is totally happy with this and doesn't catch this:
class A:
    a: str
    def __init__(self, a: str):
        self.a = a

a: str
for a in iter_attribute([A('a'), A('b'), A('c')], 'b'):
    print(a)

How would I correctly type this?

Since attribute may be any string, it's hard to statically type it as whatever you pass for it will decide on the class of returned object.

You can't.
attribute is dynamic and thus not expressible using static typing.
getattr() suffers from the same problem, and it is type hinted as returning Any:
@overload
def getattr(o: object, name: str, /) -> Any: ...

The solution is to refactor your code so that you don't have to rely on dynamic constructs. You can also use Any or type: ignore/mypy: ignore, but, needless to say, those should be avoided if you want to take advantage of static typing.
